# What is the difference between `return timer` and `clearInterval(timer)` in `async/await` in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, async-await, frontend, settimeout, setinterval

I have two async functions, and each has its `setInterval` callback.

First one:

```
timer = null;
r = 0;

async function t() {
    // return timer
    if (timer) return(timer);
    timer = setInterval(() => { 
        r += 10
        if (r === 100) clearInterval(timer);
        console.log('timer', timer, 'r', r) 
    }, 1000)
}

console.time('timer')
console.log(await t())
console.timeEnd('timer')
```

Second one:

```
timer1 = null;
r1 = 0;

async function t1() {
    // clearInterval timer1
    if (timer1) clearInterval(timer1);
    timer1 = setInterval(() => { 
        r1 += 10
        if (r1 === 100) clearInterval(timer1);
        console.log('timer1', timer1, 'r1', r1) 
    }, 1000)
}

console.time('timer1')
console.log(await t1())
console.timeEnd('timer1')
```

But when I ran them, they did same things, same outputs like following:

```
timer 18 r 10
timer 18 r 20
timer 18 r 30
timer 18 r 40
timer 18 r 50
timer 18 r 60
timer 18 r 70
timer 18 r 80
timer 18 r 90
timer 18 r 100
```

The second output is same as above:

```
timer1 23 r1 10
timer1 23 r1 20
timer1 23 r1 30
timer1 23 r1 40
timer1 23 r1 50
timer1 23 r1 60
timer1 23 r1 70
timer1 23 r1 80
timer1 23 r1 90
timer1 23 r1 100
```

My questions:

1. Did they do same things? What's the difference?
2. Obviously, I did different things in each function, 1st is `return (timer)`, 2nd is `clearInterval(timer)`, but the 1st does not return `timerId` in per interval, and 2nd does not `clearInterval(timerId)` then it should generates a new `timerId` in per interval, right? Why?

```js
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

function loadScript(url) {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = url;
    document.body.appendChild(script);

  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    if (script.readyState) { // IE
      script.onreadystatechange = function change() {
        if (script.readyState === 'loaded' || script.readyState === 'complete') {
          resolve();
        }
      };
    } else { // Others
      script.onload = function load() {
        resolve();
      };
    }
  });
}

export default class LazyloadMap extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    loading: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string, PropTypes.element]), // loading effects
    url: PropTypes.string, // SDK url
    onload: PropTypes.func, // load success
    onfail: PropTypes.func, // load failed
  }

  static defaultProps = {
    loading: 'Map was in loading', // string | ReactNode
    url: 'http://api.map.baidu.com/api?v=2.0&ak=***************************&callback=initializeBMap',
    onload: () => {},
    onfail: (e) => { alert(`加载地图失败，请重试: ${e}；`); },
  }

  static timer = null;
  static record = 0;

  static initialized() {
    const timeout = 1e4;

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (
        window.BMap &&
        typeof window.BMap === 'object' &&
        !('apiLoad' in window.BMap)
      ) {
        resolve(window.BMap);
      } else {
   
        // if timer has been initialized, does create a new `timer`
        // and clear it. Another way is just return the old `timer`,
        // i have tried the diff ways, but i am very confusing with that
        // so i sent this post, any one can help me? thanks in advanced.
        if (LazyloadMap.timer) {
          clearInterval(LazyloadMap.timer);
        }

        LazyloadMap.timer = setInterval(() => {
          LazyloadMap.record += 10;

          if (
            window.BMap &&
            typeof window.BMap === 'object' &&
            !('apiLoad' in window.BMap)
          ) {
            resolve(window.BMap);
            clearInterval(LazyloadMap.timer);
          }

          if (LazyloadMap.record >= timeout) {
            clearInterval(LazyloadMap.timer);
            reject(new Error('加载超时， 请重试'));
          }
        }, 10);
      }
    });
  }

  state = {
    loaded: false
  }

  async componentWillMount() {
    const { url, onload, onfail } = this.props;
    const onLoadSuccess = () => {
      this.setState({
        loaded: true,
      }, () => {
        onload && onload(window.BMap);
      });
    };

    if (!window.BMap) {
      try {
        console.time('componentWillMount:await-load-Bmap-used');
        await loadScript(url);
        await LazyloadMap.initialized();
        console.timeEnd('componentWillMount:await-load-Bmap-used');

        onLoadSuccess(window.BMap);
      } catch (e) {
        onfail && onfail(e instanceof Error ? e : new Error(e));
      }
    } else {
      onLoadSuccess(window.BMap);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return this.state.loaded ? this.props.children : this.props.loading;
  }
}

// flag to records whether BMap SDK was initialized,
// if it did BMap will be an object
window.BMap = undefined;

// after loadScript(url) server does return `BMap` SDK, it returned following JavaScript code
// so i use a `timer` to listening `loaded` attribute
/* (function () {
  window.BMap_loadScriptTime = (new Date).getTime();
  window.BMap = window.BMap || {};
  window.BMap.apiLoad = function () {
    delete window.BMap.apiLoad;
    if (typeof initializeBMap == "function") {
      initializeBMap()
    }
  };
  var s = document.createElement('script');
  s.src = 'http://api.map.baidu.com/getscript?v=2.0&ak=**********************&services=&t=20180629105706';
  document.body.appendChild(s);
})(); */
window.initializeBMap = LazyloadMap.initialized;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/prop-types@15.6/prop-types.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your promises are never resolving... Is that normal? :/ Your code is definitely weird, could you explain what are you trying to achieve? It could really help.

Comment: What is the goal of this code? From what it looks like, it's not doing anything useful.

Comment: You don't need to construct a promise. Thats what `async` does for you

Comment: It looks like the first one is unalterable if it's hit multiple times.  No matter how many times `t()` is hit, it won't start/restart the timer, but that's not the case for `t1()`.  It looks like `t1()` can be hit multiple times and it will "refresh" the timer.  It just clears the old one and starts a new one.  What happens when you hit either method multiple times before it finishes?

Comment: I'd say that the difference doesn't matter since both codes don't work - you never resolve the promise.

Comment: The difference would only surface if you actually called your functions multiple times. In your example, the code path that differs is never actually taken.

Comment: @sjahan i used this for a React.Component with a lazy load third JS SDK. In this Component  it waits the third JS SDK `loaded` event,  So i used a timer `interval` to waits the third global object within SDK. You can see what i did in edited post's pictures.

Comment: Just saying, but pictures of code is never the proper way to share code.

Comment: `setInterval` is certainly the ugliest way to wait for something. Doesn't your `BMap` loading give you a Promise or at least a callback? It would feel quite normal in 2018, when you do something async, you return a Promise.

Comment: @sjahan Yeah, you are right. show you my code. and `BMap` have a callback function too. You could see it on the lowest line.

Comment: @JosephMarikle 
new version of code snippet after edited post. and it is very clearly to see what i wanna do.

Comment: @Vuchan if there is a callback function, why do you have to wait with `setInterval`? When your callback function is called, one could expect everything is ready to be used. Otherwise, this `initializeBMap` callback would be quite stupid.

Comment: @sjahan Although it works well, But i think u don't know why i did them till now. I am sorry for that.